# Remove unwanted characters ([],) from a List

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I am completing a List with data returned from an XML API.

I am now gain the data in the format I require and have the function to put those `var's` into a list as follows

```
List data = [
    "Line:", pln, 
    "\n\nLat:", lat,
    "\n\nLong:", long,
    ];
```

It prints like

```
[Line:, P1,
Lat:, x.xxxxx,
Long:, x.xxxxx]
```

The characters necessary to construct my List such as `[]` and `,`are not wanted in the final print and I can't get rid of them.

I only want the characters within the quotemarks, such as from `[Line:, P1,` I just want `Line: value`, but without the other characters the List function won't work.

Thank you

Update

It is used as `metadata` and added to a map marker, which expands a pop-up upon clicking and shows this data as a list with `\n\n` adding a new line break

```
metadata.setString("key_poi", data.toString());

mapScene.addMapMarker(mapMarker);
```

Comment: Don't you want to change your `toString` equivalent to: `'Line: $pln\n\nLat: $lat\n\n Long: $long'` rather than building this list of 6 strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide the code, but I guess you're doing this:

```
print(data);
```

`data` is a list, so it's printing the list.

What you probably want to do is convert the list to a String - by joining each element of the list to the other.  There's a function for that - `join` - so try this:

```
print(data.join());
```

Note `join` can take a separator argument - and you can probably use it to get rid of those ugly `\n`'s you have in your code.

In fact, I'd probably do this instead:

```
List data = [
 "Line: $pln", 
 "Lat: $lat",
 "Long: $long",
];
print(data.join("\n\n"));
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have added an update to give you an idea of how it is implemented. I have tried to pass your revision to my ```addMapMarker``` and it is displaying on 1 line and with the unwanted characters still.  I pass ```data``` to the function which adds it to a pop-up

Comment: Have adapted your version and it works, thank you for your help.